# How do I call my output in a table format so that I can query it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

The formatted set of code gives me output in a tabular format. 
I need to figure out a way to name this set of code like we name a table.

I need to insert my output values in another table.

This seems like a simple task but I am not able to figure out how to insert a name.

```
 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlhandle output, @Data1, @Data2
```

I tried calling the program using this ^ but executing just this statement does not give me an output.

This is how the program looks like.

```
declare @Data1 xml, @Data2 xml

select @Data1 = 
(
    select * 
    from (select * from Test1 except select * from Test2) as a
    for xml raw('Data')
)

select @Data2 = 
(
    select * 
    from (select * from Test2 except select * from Test1) as a
    for xml raw('Data')
)

;with CTE1 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data1.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)    
), CTE2 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data2.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)     
)
select
    isnull(C1.ID, C2.ID) as ID, isnull(C1.Name, C2.Name) as Name, C1.Value as Value1, C2.Value as Value2
from CTE1 as C1
    full outer join CTE2 as C2 on C2.ID = C1.ID and C2.Name = C1.Name
where
not
(
    C1.Value is null and C2.Value is null or
    C1.Value is not null and C2.Value is not null and C1.Value = C2.Value
)
```

P.S I'm sorry if I am not able to explain the problem really well. I am still learning.

Comment: Why not just use another CTE? Or maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Maybe you need to use a variable in your calling code?

Comment: Does your table already exist? If so do you want to add to it or drop it and make a new one with just this latest data?

Comment: Need to call this whole program with a single statement. I need to name this program so that I can use that name later to query the results. Let me know if you get it. @SeanLange

Comment: My table already exists. I need to add to it. I need to add the output of this code into that table. @CaiusJard

Comment: You need to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example For your case it means DDL plus sample data population.

Comment: Take a look at the nodes method. I think it will get you closer to what you are trying to do. It lets you query the shredded XML.

Comment: Nope...clear as mud. This isn't a program, it is some t-sql. Maybe you mean you want to make this into a stored procedure? If the code is producing the results and you want to "output this into that table" you should just add an insert before the select.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, a tiny hint: There is some nice [magic in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). For example, the expression `[mcve]` will automatically be translated to your link. I do this here: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be saying that your code works fine, you run your stored procedure in SSMS and it produces the results in the grid, that you want.. You just want it going into an existing table rather than into the SSMS results grid

It's probably going to be as simple as adding `INSERT INTO table` between the CTEs and the SELECT:

```
with CTE1 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data1.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)    
), CTE2 as (
    select
        T.C.value('../@ID', 'bigint') as ID,
        T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as Name,
        T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    from @Data2.nodes('Data/@*') as T(C)     
)
```

```
INSERT INTO table
```

```
select
    isnull(C1.ID, C2.ID) as ID, isnull(C1.Name, C2.Name) as Name, C1.Value as Value1, C2.Value as Value2
from CTE1 as C1
    full outer join CTE2 as C2 on C2.ID = C1.ID and C2.Name = C1.Name
where
not
(
    C1.Value is null and C2.Value is null or
    C1.Value is not null and C2.Value is not null and C1.Value = C2.Value
)
```

If the query is not outputting a set of columns identical to the columns in the table, then name the columns to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO table (theId, theName, theValue1, theValue2)
```

It's probably a good idea to be explicit anyway because if someone adds a column to your table in future it will certainly break your procedure. If you're explicit about the columns it might still break, but rather than being a certainty it'll only break if someone adds a column that is "NOT NULL" and they don't specify what the column default value is

Comment: Pretty sure this is what they are looking for but so hard to tell. +1 from me if for nothing else an exception guess. :D

Comment: Yea, just watch him come back now with a "I'm getting a pk violation" :)

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I wanted to do. I knew it was something really small I was missing. My bad. This worked like a charm. @CaiusJard